# Datepicker - year only?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use Datepicker control, but with only YEAR displayed and shown to user for edit. Is it possible to remove the month and day fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DatePicker control in the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit doesn't have that kind of direct customization!

You'll have to change the picker control and the full page it uses; you can check [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization) for some info about DatePicker customization, though it is quite sparse...

Comment: How about that scrollable control, is that only part of datepicker or available as standalone control?

Comment: The scrolable control can be used outside of the DatePicker, but I personally have never used it as such!

Answer (score 2):

`Silverlight Toolkit` comes in source codes also, so you can add code files that used `DatePicker` and modify `Picker Page`. I don't see easiest way to modify/reproduce date picker

Answer (score 1):

Check out Telerik controls for Windows Phone. It provides a very easy way to do formatting of the DatePicker popup. In your case I believe you would want to use this xaml

```
<telerikInput:RadDatePicker x:Name="radDatePicker" SelectorFormat="y" />
```

Here's the documentation for customizing Telerik controls [Telerik DatePicker documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddatepicker-features-formatting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used ValueStringFormat="{}{0:yyyy} for toolkit:DatePicker, which displays only Year but sadly still shows days and months for editing. Or you can use 
[Longlistpicker](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API) which is described in detail here.